# Executing Lua function from a string

Tags: c++, xml, lua

I need to execute a lua function which is part of an XML file. I will parse the XML and load the entire function as a string.

When I tried to execute **lua_pcall** it gives me `attempt to call a nil value`.
But when I attempted to remove the function part and use the inner logic alone, it worked fine to me. I need to understand should I need to carry any additional step in order to execute as a function.

Initialization:

```
/* the Lua interpreter */
lua_State *luaState;
// initialize Lua 
luaState = luaL_newstate();
lua_register(luaState, "getValue", get_value);
lua_register(luaState, "setValue", set_value);
// load Lua base libraries 
luaL_openlibs(luaState);
```

*Working*:
XML

```
-- lua script to be executed by this algorithm
-- use following API calls to get and set function block data
-- local IN1 = getValue("IN1")
-- setValue("OUT1", value)
 setValue("RequestAccepted", "true");

-- lua script
```

C++ Code:

```
TAlgoTable::iterator iter = algoTable.find("RequestAccepted");
if (luaL_dostring(luaState, iter->second.c_str()))
{
    printf("Failure at Algorithm : 'RequestAccepted' Reason : %s", lua_tostring(luaState, -1));
}
```

Not working:

```
 -- lua script to be executed by this algorithm
function RequestAccepted()
 -- use following API calls to get and set function block data
 -- local IN1 = getValue("IN1")
 -- setValue("OUT1", value)
 setValue("RequestAccepted", "true");

end -- lua script
```

C++ code:

```
lua_getglobal(luaState, "RequestAccepted"); // function to be called 
if (lua_pcall(luaState, 0, 0, 0)) {
    printf("Failure at Algorithm : 'RequestAccepted' Reason : %s", lua_tostring(luaState, -1));
}
```

Comment: In the first example, you call `lua_dostring()` to parse and execute the Lua code.  In the second example, you aren't, unless you have left that bit out.

Answer (score 1):

I found and understood that I need to load the function into the buffer.
The below link helped me to resolve
http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/minimal-example-lua-function-cpp.html

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects, the way I did this was to create a Lua reference using (forgive the formatting, copy and paste):

```
int SParamSchemaNode::parseScript(lua_State* L,
                                  const char* arglist,
                                  const char* body)
{
std::ostringstream bufToParse;

// save old stack top so we can clean up errors from the first
// try if the second succeeds
int oldStackTop = lua_gettop(L);
bufToParse << "return function(" << arglist << ") return ("
           << body << ") end";
if (luaL_dostring(L, bufToParse.str().c_str()))
{
    int parseError1_pos = lua_gettop(L);
    bufToParse.str(std::string());  // reset bufToParse string to empty
    bufToParse << "return function(" << arglist << ") "
               << body << " end";
    if (luaL_dostring(L, bufToParse.str().c_str()))
    {
        // since the error message includes the script which we're trying
        // to parse, the result has unbounded length; so use another
        // ostringstream to hold the error message
        std::ostringstream errmsg;
        errmsg << "Errors parsing the following script:" << std::endl;
        errmsg << body << std::endl << std::endl;
        errmsg << "Parser error when interpreting as an expression:" << std::endl;
        errmsg << lua_tostring(L, parseError1_pos) << std::endl << std::endl;
        errmsg << "Parser error when interpreting as a function body:" << std::endl;
        errmsg << lua_tostring(L, -1);
        ERROR_ReportError(errmsg.str().c_str());
    }
}
if (DEBUG)
{
    std::cout << "Successfully loaded chunk: " << bufToParse.str() << std::endl;
}
int ref = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
lua_settop(L, oldStackTop);
return ref;
}
```

Then I stored this in (for example) a `SParameterDefinition::m_applicableScriptRef` member, and called it using:

```
bool SParameterDefinition::isApplicable(SAbstractComponent* cmpt, int index)
{
if (m_applicableScriptRef == LUA_NOREF)
{
    return true;
}

lua_State* L = schema()->luaState();
// fetch the function to call from the registry
lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, m_applicableScriptRef);
// push the "cmpt" argument
SWIG_UC_push_SAbstractComponent(L, cmpt);
int nargs = 1;
if (m_isInstanced)
{
    lua_pushnumber(L, index);
    nargs++;
}
// protected call of the function (nargs arguments, 1 result,
//   no special error handler function)
int script_result = lua_pcall(L, nargs, 1, 0);
if (script_result != 0)
{
    std::ostringstream errmsgBuf;
    errmsgBuf << "Error while calling applicable script for "
              << "parameter " << m_name << ":\n";
    errmsgBuf << lua_tostring(L, -1);
    ERROR_ReportError(errmsgBuf.str().c_str());
}
if (! lua_isboolean(L, -1))
{
    report_type_error("Applicable",
                      m_name.c_str(), "boolean",
                      luaL_typename(L, -1));
}
bool result = (lua_toboolean(L, -1) != 0);
lua_pop(L, 1);
return result;
}
```

You might not need the full complexity here, but the essential points are wrapping the body in `return function() ... end`, evaluating it with `luaL_dostring`, and then storing the result of that script using `luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX)`.